# Magento 2 get option label from custom admin dropdown

Tags: magento2, labels, dropdown-options

For my custom plugin I created an options array like this:

path : => \Vendor\App\Block\System\Config;

```
namespace Vendor\App\Block\System\Config;

class NatureIva implements \Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface
{
    public function toOptionArray(){
        
        $optionGroup = [ 
            ['value' => "Scegli", 'label' => __("Scegli...")],
            [
                'label' => 'N1',
                'value' => [
                    [
                        'label' => __("N1 - escluse ex art.15 "),
                        'value' => 'N1'
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'N2',
                'value' => [
                    [
                        'label' => __("N2 - non soggette"),
                        'value' => 'N2'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N2.1 - non soggette ad IVA ai sensi degli artt. da 7 a 7-septies del DPR 633/72"),
                        'value' => 'N2.1'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N2.2 - altri casi"),
                        'value' => 'N2.2'
                    ],
                ],
            ], 
            [
                'label' => 'N3',
                'value' => [
                    [
                        'label' => __("N3 - non imponibili"),
                        'value' => 'N3'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N3.1 - esportazioni"),
                        'value' => 'N3.1'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N3.2 - cessioni intracomunitarie"),
                        'value' => 'N3.2'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N3.3 - cessioni verso San Marino"),
                        'value' => 'N3.3'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N3.4 - operazioni assimilate alle cessioni all'esportazione"),
                        'value' => 'N3.4'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N3.5 - a seguito di dichiarazioni d'intento"),
                        'value' => 'N3.5'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N3.6 - altre operazioni che non concorrono alla formazione del plafond"),
                        'value' => 'N3.6'
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'N4',
                'value' => [
                    [
                        'label' => __("N4 - esenti "),
                        'value' => 'N4'
                    ],
                ],
            ], 
            [
                'label' => 'N5',
                'value' => [
                    [
                        'label' => __("N5 - regime del margine / IVA non esposta in fattura "),
                        'value' => 'N5'
                    ],
                ],
            ], 
            [
                'label' => 'N6',
                'value' => [
                    [
                        'label' => __("N6 - inversione contabile"),
                        'value' => 'N6'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N6.1 - cessione di rottami e altri materiali di recupero"),
                        'value' => 'N6.1'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N6.2 - cessione di oro e argento puro"),
                        'value' => 'N6.2'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N6.3 - subappalto nel settore edile"),
                        'value' => 'N6.3'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N6.4 - cessione di fabbricati"),
                        'value' => 'N6.4'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N6.5 - cessione di telefoni cellulari"),
                        'value' => 'N6.5'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N6.6 - cessione di prodotti elettronici"),
                        'value' => 'N6.6'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N6.7 - prestazioni comparto edile e settori connessi"),
                        'value' => 'N6.7'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N6.8  - operazioni settore energetico"),
                        'value' => 'N6.8'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N6.9 - altri casi"),
                        'value' => 'N6.9'
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'N7',
                'value' => [
                    [
                        'label' => __("N7 - IVA assolta in altro stato UE"),
                        'value' => 'N7'
                    ],
                ],
            ],     
        ];
        
        return $optionGroup;
}
}
```

I already added the necessary code in \Vendor\App\etc\adminhtml\system.xml:

```
<field id="natura_iva" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="15" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Natura Iva</label>
                    <source_model>Fattura24\AppFatturazione\Block\System\Config\NatureIva</source_model>
                    <comment>Specifica la Natura IVA predefinita per Aliquote pari a 0%</comment>
                </field>
```

I can see the option list in my menu correctly.

in my Helper I use `$this->getConfig('fattura24/fatture/natura_iva', $storeId);` to get the option value selected.

Now I would like to add the label text related to that option. For instance, if I choose N3.3 as option, I would like to retrieve also its label, that is "N3.3 - cessioni verso San Marino".

Thanks to all in advance

Answer (score 0):

use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

> **Use this code to get your system.xml field value**

```
    const ENABLE_MENU = 'sectionname/groupname/fieldname';

    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        ..............................................................
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        ..............................................................
    ) {
        ..............................................................
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        ..............................................................
    }

    public function setStoreScope()
    {
        return ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
    }

    public function getSystemValue()
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(static::SYSTEM_VAL, $this->setStoreScope());
    }
```

> **Try this code to get your label value**

```
<?php
// get your system.xml value here
//$system_val = $block->getSystemValue(); // $system_val = $this->getSystemValue();
$system_val = "N3.4";

        $optionGroup = [
            ['value' => "Scegli", 'label' => __("Scegli...")],
            [
                'label' => 'N1',
                'value' => [
                    [
                        'label' => __("N1 - escluse ex art.15 "),
                        'value' => 'N1'
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'N2',
                'value' => [
                    [
                        'label' => __("N2 - non soggette"),
                        'value' => 'N2'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N2.1 - non soggette ad IVA ai sensi degli artt. da 7 a 7-septies del DPR 633/72"),
                        'value' => 'N2.1'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N2.2 - altri casi"),
                        'value' => 'N2.2'
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'N3',
                'value' => [
                    [
                        'label' => __("N3 - non imponibili"),
                        'value' => 'N3'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N3.1 - esportazioni"),
                        'value' => 'N3.1'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N3.2 - cessioni intracomunitarie"),
                        'value' => 'N3.2'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N3.3 - cessioni verso San Marino"),
                        'value' => 'N3.3'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N3.4 - operazioni assimilate alle cessioni all'esportazione"),
                        'value' => 'N3.4'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N3.5 - a seguito di dichiarazioni d'intento"),
                        'value' => 'N3.5'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N3.6 - altre operazioni che non concorrono alla formazione del plafond"),
                        'value' => 'N3.6'
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'N4',
                'value' => [
                    [
                        'label' => __("N4 - esenti "),
                        'value' => 'N4'
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'N5',
                'value' => [
                    [
                        'label' => __("N5 - regime del margine / IVA non esposta in fattura "),
                        'value' => 'N5'
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'N6',
                'value' => [
                    [
                        'label' => __("N6 - inversione contabile"),
                        'value' => 'N6'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N6.1 - cessione di rottami e altri materiali di recupero"),
                        'value' => 'N6.1'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N6.2 - cessione di oro e argento puro"),
                        'value' => 'N6.2'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N6.3 - subappalto nel settore edile"),
                        'value' => 'N6.3'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N6.4 - cessione di fabbricati"),
                        'value' => 'N6.4'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N6.5 - cessione di telefoni cellulari"),
                        'value' => 'N6.5'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N6.6 - cessione di prodotti elettronici"),
                        'value' => 'N6.6'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N6.7 - prestazioni comparto edile e settori connessi"),
                        'value' => 'N6.7'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N6.8  - operazioni settore energetico"),
                        'value' => 'N6.8'
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __("N6.9 - altri casi"),
                        'value' => 'N6.9'
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'N7',
                'value' => [
                    [
                        'label' => __("N7 - IVA assolta in altro stato UE"),
                        'value' => 'N7'
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];

foreach ($optionGroup as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $key_val => $value_val) {
                foreach ((array)$value_val as $val) {
                    if(is_array($val)){
                        if(count($val)){
                            if($val['value'] == $system_val){
                                //print_r($val['label']->getText());
                                echo "Your Value Label is ".$val['label']->getText();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: should I copy the $optionGroup Array in my \Vendor\App\Helper\Data.php ? I would like to get all array values in my helper, since I already have got it in my \Vendor\App\Block\System\Config\NatureIva. Is that possible?

Comment: both file in possible.